# Using a fixed multidimensional array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, plist

Being a total newbie with Objective-C coming from C#, I keep finding conflicting info regarding arrays in Obj-C.

Looking at the question answered in this post: [objective-c multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459931/objective-c-multi-dimensional-array)

I am trying to store fixed data in my iPhone app using multidimensional arrays. The data will never change, however each item must be kept sorted in the order that it is added to the array,as each indexed entry corresponds to data in a different array, held at the same index.

e.g.
    Array 1: (10, 20, 26, 30...etc)
    Array 2: (A, B, C, D....etc) where Array 1 [0] corresponds to Array 2 [0] (10 corresponds to A)

My question is, is there a way to store this data in a plist, whilst keeping it ordered? The data is formatted exactly as in the post included, however I would rather store it away from the class files. The arrays will only be read from, never added to or changed.

Comment: storing arrays in plist files is completely ok. I'm not talking about dictionaries, which would had break the order of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode makes it really cool to create and edit plist files.
Add a plist file to the project, edit it to create your nested arrays and then the problem become less hard.

[Reading the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044213/plist-array-to-nsaray-no-objects), isn't much a problem.